# How to set a default value to a DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my MVC application I want to set default values to the `DateTime` parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime startDate)
{
    var Odata = _db.sp_BudgetedVsActualTabular(startDate).ToList();    
    string[] monthName = new string[12];    
    for (int i = 0; i < 12;i++ )
    {
        DateTime date = startDate;
        date = date.AddMonths(i);
        monthName[i] = date.ToString("MMMM") + " " + date.Year.ToString();     
    }

    ViewBag.startDate = new SelectList(_db.DaymonFinancialYears, "startDate", "DateRange");    
    var MonthName = monthName.ToList();
    ViewBag.Bdata = Odata;
    ViewBag.Cdata = MonthName;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot set a `null` to a `DateTime` but you can use a [`Nullable DateTime`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime) parameter instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime? startDate = null )
{ 
    if (startDate == null)
    {
        startDate  = new DateTime(2016, 06, 01);
    }
    //You should pass startDate.Value
    var Odata = _db.sp_BudgetedVsActualTabular(startDate.Value).ToList();

}
```

Comment: i need to set the date to 2014-06-01   so it will be like    '[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime? startDate = null )
{ 
}'    ?

Comment: @simba...You can give the `startDate` a default value = `null` then you can set it to `2014-06-01` if it was `null` in your `BudgetVSActualTabular` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [default keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) with this syntax

```
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime startDate = default(DateTime))
```

This will make possible to call the method without passing any parameter and inside your method the `startDate` variable will be equal to [DateTime.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you need the default to be a specific date instead of `DateTime.MinValue` you could write a simple test

```
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime startDate = default(DateTime))
{
    if(startDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        startDate = new DateTime(2014,6,1);

    // After the check for a missing parameter pass the startDate as before
    var Odata = _db.sp_BudgetedVsActualTabular(startDate).ToList();
    .....
}
```

Comment: i need to set the date to 2014-06-01 so it will be like '[HttpPost] public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime? startDate = null ) { }' ?

Comment: If this is the case just add a test before using the passed value

Answer (score 1):

Named and optional (default) parameters are available starting from C# 4.0. in case you're using an older version, you may overload your method like:

```
 public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular()
 {
      return BudgetVSActualTabular(new DateTime(2014,6,1));
 }
```

Comment: but i wanted to assign a particular value not any value or null. So i had to use what Steve and the other user suggested me.

Comment: @simba You can test before call method, and change the overload ( Check my updated answer )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the DateTime to be nullable `public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime? startDate)`.

Inside your controller you can use DateTime.HasValue to set a default if the DateTime is null.

`var nonNullableDate = startDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value : new DateTime();`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BudgetVSActualTabular(DateTime? startDate)
{
    var nonNullableDate = startDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value : new DateTime();
    var Odata = _db.sp_BudgetedVsActualTabular(nonNullableDate).ToList();    
    string[] monthName = new string[12];    
    for (int i = 0; i < 12;i++ )
    {
        DateTime date = nonNullableDate;
        date = date.AddMonths(i);
        monthName[i] = date.ToString("MMMM") + " " + date.Year.ToString();     
    }

    ViewBag.startDate = new SelectList(_db.DaymonFinancialYears, "startDate", "DateRange");    
    var MonthName = monthName.ToList();
    ViewBag.Bdata = Odata;
    ViewBag.Cdata = MonthName;
    return View();
}
```