# Default property value on generated Linq-to-Sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, orm

In a project of mine we're using Linq-to-Sql to interface with our SQL server.

The project contains a `.dbml` file containing the definition of a class named `User`, which correlates to a `Users` table.
The classes are automatically generated by visual studio, after designing their scheme using Visual Studio built-in tool.

One of the properties of `User` is of type `DateTime`, so when we're instantiating a `User` object this field gets the default value of `1/1/0 00:00`.
This is a problem because we have a `minValue` which we cannot predate.

I searched for a solution regarding how to give the class property a default value, but I could only find ways to set a default value for the table, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there any way to set the property default value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value to a DateTime parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897427/how-to-set-a-default-value-to-a-datetime-parameter)

Comment: Not quite. Since the code is automatically generated and might be regenerated at any time by the Visual Studio Tool I cannot modify the code directly. I guess there is a setting in the tool I need to change...